# Can I put restriction to access particular group of MS team while app registration in Azure portal under my tenant?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have registered an app in AAD and as a admin I want to provide permission for user to read or access the data of particular group list not all group available in my MS team account. How can be achieve this any idea?

Comment: are you using managed identity on-behalf implementation accessing Microsoft teams resources ?

Comment: Not sure, but I am using Application permission for MS team, and getting the access token but posting this url https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/v2.0/token.How can I check this?

Answer (score 0):

No. Azure AD app doesn't provide such a feature that scopes Microsoft Graph application permissions to specific Microsoft Teams/Groups.

The client credential flow is used to as an authorization grant typically when the client is acting on its own behalf. When you give `Group.Read.All` or `Files.Read.All` or other similar application permissions, it means the client has access to all the files/groups across the entire tenant.

You can achieve this by implement the business logic in your code. For example, providing a configuration file which includes the particular groups'/teams' object ids. And then restrict the access for users to only these groups/teams by checking if the object ids (which users are trying to access) are in the configuration file.